# Using SoX in Linux with PHP

Tags: php, linux, audio, sox

I m trying to use Sox lib to mix (concatenate) two sound files in PHP. I can do it on MacOS with command line like;

```
./sox -m sound1.wav sound2.wav output.wav
```

I m also trying this on my web server. I downloaded compressed file from Sox official page [sox-14.2.2.tar.gz](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sox/) and extracted them on my server. But there are lots of files, its not like on MacOS. I thought that `sox.1` file can be executed, and tried something like;

```
echo exec('./sox.1 -m sound1.wav sound2.wav output.wav');
```

But it just returns the text in line 108. I think it's not executable. I'm stuck here right now. I need to concatenate 2 sound files in PHP.

If there is any way please let me know?

Comment: The `.gz` file that you downloaded is only the source code to SoX. The `sox.1` file won't do what you want -- it's a text file containing the `man` page (documentation) for SoX. To get SoX to work on your server, you'll need to compile the source code on your server, thereby creating the executable.

Answer (score 0):

You've downloaded the source, but now need to build, make & install before you can use sox on your web server.

```
tar -xvf sox-14.2.2.tar.gz
```

That will extract it, then inside the extracted folder you should run `./configure`, followed by `make` then `make install`. Any deps or isssues will be seen during this stage. Once all installed, you can then use sox on your webserver like you do from your Mac. 
So you'd need something like

```
echo exec('sox -m sound1.wav sound2.wav output.wav');
```